# RabbitMQ Flow Control Not Working (Java Client)

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I'm constructing my RabbitMQ (RabbitMQ 3.6.5, Erlang R16B03) connection as follows:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setHost(App.rabbitMQServer);
factory.setVirtualHost(App.rabbitVirtualHost);
factory.setRequestedHeartbeat(5);
factory.setConnectionTimeout(5000);
factory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);        
factory.setNetworkRecoveryInterval(5000);

Map<String, Object> clientProperties = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> capabilities = new HashMap<>();
capabilities.put("connection.blocked", true);
clientProperties.put("capabilities", capabilities);
factory.setClientProperties(clientProperties);

_connection = factory.newConnection();

_channel = _connection.createChannel();

_connection.addBlockedListener(new BlockedListener() {
    public void handleBlocked(String reason) throws IOException {               
        connectionIsBlocked = true;
        log.warn("RabbitMQ connection blocked");
    }

    public void handleUnblocked() throws IOException {
        connectionIsBlocked = false;
        log.warn("RabbitMQ connection unblocked");
    }
});
```

The connection looks ok in the management web console - the capabilities are present however the BlockedListener methods are never called. What am I missing?

Incidentally, I have another process written in Go which also never calls its flow listener...

```
flow := ch.NotifyFlow(make(chan bool))
go func() {
    for f := range flow {
        shouldFailoverToSQS = f
        log.Infof("Flow status changed")
    }
}()
```

Comment: I've tested this code with a local Docker instance running RabbitMQ 3.6.10, Erlang 19.3. When tweaking set_vm_memory_high_watermark I'm seeing the blocked listener respond appropriately. I'm wondering if either the server is becoming CPU bound before hitting its memory limit and not able to send out flow control messages or there's a problem with the earlier version of the server code.

Answer (score 0):

I was confusing the BlockedListener and the FlowListener (which is deprecated).